# c#, Nlog and change target

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, event-viewer

i am running windows service,
and i want when i run in debugto to write to console
and when as service to event viewer.

in powershell i set

```
New-EventLog –LogName Application –Source "mySource"
```

I have this `nlog.config`:

```
<nlog>
<targets>
<target name="debugger" type="Debugger" layout="${logger}::${message}"/>
<target name="console" type="Console" layout="${logger}::${message}"/>
<target name="file" type="File" layout="${longdate} ${logger}::${message}" fileName="${basedir}/Logs/${shortdate}.log"/>
<target name="eventLog" type="eventlog" layout="${logger}::${message}" source="mySource"/>
</targets>
<rules>
<logger name="" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="debugger"/>
<logger name="" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console"/>
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file"/>
<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="eventLog" />
</rules>
</nlog>
```

i do init when service start :

```
    public static void InitLogger()
    {
        NLog.Targets.Target target = null;

        target = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("eventlog");

        NLog.Config.SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForTargetLogging(target, LogLevel.Info);
        LogManager.Configuration.Reload();

    }
```

to test this i change it in both cases to write to "eventlog"
even in debug mode. but it is not working correctly when using the event viewer (VS is running in admin mode)

[image]

i set in each class

```
private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

what is missing?

Comment: update:  i found the even viewer writing here (see pic)
https://pasteboard.co/I5ngzT8.png

Comment: Could be nice to also see your `nlog.config`

Comment: Cannot see any target called `eventlog`

Comment: @RolfKristensen i updated previous answer

Comment: You should only have one NLog-configuration. Not both in app.config and nlog.config.

Comment: i updated the original app.config with NLog in the post

Answer (score 1):

This line will load the `NLog.config` and lookup a named target:

```
target = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("eventlog");
```

This line will discard the original NLog config (with all rules and targets) and create new one with a single target:

```
NLog.Config.SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForTargetLogging(target, LogLevel.Info);
```

This line will not do anything:

```
LogManager.Configuration.Reload();
```

I guess you are trying to add an extra target to the existing configuration. This can be done like this (Replacing all the above code):

```
LogManager.Configuration.AddRule("*", LogLevel.Info, target):
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

Btw. if you don't configure the `Source`-property for the EventLog-target, then it will use AppDomain.FriendlyName

Comment: the problem is that the event write not to the correct place, but to this one (in red circle in the puicture)
https://pasteboard.co/I5ngzT8.png

Comment: Did you read my remark about configuring the `Source`-property for the EventLog-target ? See also https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/EventLog-target

Comment: Did you remember to delete all your faulty code, and use the `AddRule`-call that I recommneded?

Comment: Maybe check the https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging if the `Source`-property is configured correctly for the eventlog-target.

Comment: Now it write correct to event log, my target was in debug to write only to console
and as service to write only to event viewer.
currently it writes to both places after i added the AddRule